# displaying text with a small background

Tags: php, css

I am having some trouble displaying a background for some text.
The background should be displayed with (in center) with some (real)text, like a button however not clickable.
I have a background picture of 150x24 pixels.
However once displayed with my css the button sizes up to 940x150.

As i am a starter with css i guess i am missing something here...

My code looks like

```
<div class="wrap"> <img src=sites/all/themes/at_subtheme/css/img/header.jpg>

    <div class="caption">

       <div class="caption-inner">
           <div class="caption-content">
              <?php if  ((( user_is_anonymous())) or (in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) ) :?>
              <h2 class="loginlink"> <a href="http://www.example.com">Login</h2></a><?php endif; ?>  
              <h2 class="mybackgroundtext">Mybackgroundtext</h2>
              <img class="button"> <img src=sites/all/themes/at_subtheme/css/img/button.jpg>
              <h2 class="headerposition">My headertext</h2>
              <h6 class="subheaderposition">mysubheadertext</h6>
              <h6 class="subsubheaderposition">Mysubsubheadertext</h6>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: without succes i applied this css to my background:
.button  {
        position:absolute; 
        margin-left:-100px;
        left:50%;
        width:200px;
        bottom:5px;
}

Comment: The css would be useful if it's causing the issue, better still if you can recreate it in a live sample (jsfiddle) or supply the relevant code for someone to be able to recreate the issue, your chances of getting a solution will be improved.

Comment: Can you provide your site url? @user25765

Comment: Its still in a dev mode on a local host. I couldnt paste the css in a comment. I will look for other ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do. I took just your button code and made a JSFIDDLE with a few options. Thanks,

[button fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewster05/jc2vdec6/3/)

```
<div class="caption"> 
    <a target="_blank" title="Microsoft" class="btn btnImgContainer" href="http://www.microsoft.com/en- us/default.aspx"> 
        <img class="myImage" src="http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-us/CMSImages/mslogo.png?version=856673f8-e6be-0476-6669-d5bf2300391d" />
    </a>  
    <a target="_blank" class="btn btnContainer" href="#">Mybackgroundtext</a>  
    <a target="_blank" class="btn btnImgBackground" href="#">My Different Button</a>

</div>

.btn {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover {
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.myImage {
    width: 100%;
    /*The height 100% distorts image*/
    height: 100%;
}
.btnImgContainer {
    width: 150px;
}
.btnContainer {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
.btnImgBackground {
    background: url("http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/abstract-background.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: white;
}
```